# quicksearch wrong selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, quick-search

I'm using jquery [quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) plugin to search through a list of elements but it seems that I'm not setting the correct selector.

The markup is like this:

```
<div id="social-stream" class="dcsns">
<div class="dcsns-content">
    <ul class="stream isotope">
        <li>

                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="section-thumb"></span>
                    <span class="section-text">5 jQuery Responsive Fullscreen Background Image Plugins | jQuery4u</span>
                    <span class="section-user"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/DesignChemical">Design Chemical</a></span>
                </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

and the plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_search").quicksearch("#socialstream .dcsns-content ul.stream isotope li .inner ", {
                noResults: '#noresults',
                loader: 'span.loading'
            });
        });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/A3q6v/) example
and here is the [website](http://outboxvision.com/test/example_4.html) version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery says isotope is inside ul.stream, but your HTML says otherwise.